# Can cp -r replace the cp -a in this case?

Tags: linux, directory, cp

If I understand correctly the option `cp -a someDir` is essentially to archive a dir i.e. to copy its contents/structure and preserve access time & access rights.
And it differs with `cp -r someDir` which does not preserve time & access rights.
When would the following make sense:
`$cp -a someDir .`
`$chown $LOGNAME:$LOGNAME someDir`
I saw these 2 commands ran by someone but it seems to me that if he just did `cp -r` in the first place he would not need the `chown` as a second step.
Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: unless he wanted to change ownership, but preserve timestamps and permissions

Comment: @user4556274 that should be an answer